# Handling floats with comma instead of points in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a few large files which I want to analyze using Google BigQuery.

It was working pretty well, except for fields with floats: I can import them only as strings since their decimals are stored as commas instead of points.

How can I work around that?

Answer (score 7):

Importing them as a string seems fine, then running an ETL inside BigQuery should be fast enough (REGEX_REPLACE + FLOAT).

```
SELECT 2*FLOAT(REGEXP_REPLACE("1,30001", ",", "."))
```